# Simple Python Regex Find pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a sentence.  I want to find all occurrences of a word that start with a specific character in that sentence.  I am very new to programming and Python, but from the little I know, this sounds like a Regex question.

What is the pattern match code that will let me find all words that match my pattern?

Many thanks in advance,

Brock

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import re
print re.findall(r'\bv\w+', thesentence)
```

will print every word in the sentence that starts with `'v'`, for example.

Using the `split` method of strings, as another answer suggests, would not identify *words*, but space-separated chunks that may include punctuation.  This `re`-based solution *does* identify words (letters and digits, net of punctuation).

Comment: This seems like a great approach, as I want to avoid commas directly after a word.  My issue is that I cant get this to work if I want the word to start with the @ symbol.  Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: add a `@?` -- an optional occurrence of `'@'` at the start of the regex' pattern, before the `\b` (you can actually omit that `\b`, since `@` then `v` will _always_ mean a word-boundary, no need to check;-).

Comment: This works perfect for me. Can u devise a method to check ending character also?. In my case the string ends with a number.

Answer (score 3):

I second the Dive Into Python recommendation.  But it's basically:

```
m = re.findall(r'\bf.*?\b', 'a fast and friendly dog')
print(m)
```

\b means word boundary, and .*? ensures we store the whole word, but back off to avoid going too far (technically, ? is called a lazy operator).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> sentence="a quick brown fox for you"
>>> pattern="fo"
>>> for word in sentence.split():
...     if word.startswith(pattern):
...         print word
...
fox
for
```

Split the sentence on spaces, use a loop to search for the pattern and print them out.

Answer (score 2):

You could do (doesn't use `re` though):

```
matching_words = [x for x in sentence.split() if x.startswith(CHAR_TO_FIND)]
```

Regular expressions work too (see the other answers) but I think this solution will be a little more readable, and as a beginner learning Python, you'll find list comprehensions (like the solution above) important to gain a comfort level with.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = "Your sentence that contains the word ROAD"
s = re.sub(r'\bROAD', 'RD.', s)

print s
```

Read: http://diveintopython3.org/regular-expressions.html

Comment: Why the replacement, and end-of-string anchor?