# Find Repeating Sublist Within Large List

Tags: python, list, sequence, repeat, sublist

I have a large list of sub-lists (approx. 16000) that I want to find where the repeating pattern starts and ends. I am not 100% sure that there is a repeat, however I have a strong reason to believe so, due to the diagonals that appear within the sub-list sequence. The structure of a list of sub-lists is preferred, as it is used that way for other things in this script. The data looks like this:

```
data = ['1100100100000010',
        '1001001000000110',
        '0010010000001100',
        '0100100000011011', etc
```

I do not have any time constraints, however the fastest method would not be frown upon. The code should be able to return the starting/ending sequence and location within the list, to be called upon in the future. If there is an arrangement of the data that would be more useful, I can try to reformat it if necessary. Python is something that I have been learning for the past few months, so I am not quite able to just create my own algorithms from scratch just yet. Thank you!

Comment: it is possible for you to use set rather that list ?

Comment: You might consider looking at suffix trees (e.g. [(1)](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-tree-application-3-longest-repeated-substring/), or rephrasing your question to "repeated substrings", as you may find more results.

Comment: @AliSAIDOMAR As I understand it, if you use set, a character can only appear once. Since the entire list is only 0 or 1, that is problematic.

Comment: @jedwards I looked into suffix trees as well as the repeated substring methods before posting. The main issue for the methods I have seen is that you must know the sequence you are looking for. In my case I do not know what it is. The only way I can think to make that work is to set that up within a for loop that tries each one, however I feel like there is probably a better way.

Comment: Could you use regex similar to what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260105/simple-python-regex-find-pattern)?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. In the text you talk about a list of sub-lists, but your example data is a list of strings, with no sub-lists. I guess you actually want to consider the list of strings as a single giant string, and you want to know if it contains a large substring that repeats exactly, with no intervening bits between the repeated sections. Is that correct?

Comment: @pat That thread has sparked an idea. Could I not create a for loop that takes sublist 1 looks to see if it occurs again, if it does, check to see if sublist 2 matches the one after the repeat of sublist 1 and so on until a threshold that indicates a repeat of the period has occurred (maybe 10 matches in a row)?

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that is a much better way to say what I want to do.

Comment: Still it   snto clear for me - do you want to treat all srigns as one gigant corpus of data, or are you looking for repeated sequences of these strings themselves? Like - if data[0:3] is '101', '111', '001', and at position 300 of data, those three strings show up again - and that is what you  want. Can't figure out.

Comment: @jsbueno No, the repeated subsequences must be adjacent. There are no intervening bits between the repeated sections.

Comment: Hopefully, my algorithm isn't too hard to understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some fairly simple code that scans a string for adjacent repeating subsequences. Set `minrun` to the length of the smallest subsequences that you want to check. For each match, the code prints the starting index of the first subsequence, the length of the subsequence, and the subsequence itself.

```
data = [
    '1100100100000010',
    '1001001000000110',
    '0010010000001100',
    '0100100000011011',
]
data = ''.join(data)

minrun = 3
lendata = len(data)
for runlen in range(minrun, lendata // 2):
    i = 0
    while i < lendata - runlen * 2:
        s1 = data[i:i + runlen]
        s2 = data[i + runlen:i + runlen * 2]
        if s1 == s2:
            print(i, runlen, s1)
            i += runlen 
        else:
            i += 1
```

**output**

```
1 3 100
4 3 100
8 3 000
15 3 010
18 3 010
23 3 000
32 3 001
38 3 000
47 3 001
53 3 000
17 15 001001000000110
32 15 001001000000110
```

Note that we get the same sequence of length 3 at index 15 and 18 = 15 + 3 : `010`; that indicates that there are 3 adjacent copies of `010`. Similarly, there are 3 adjacent copies of the sequence at index 17 of length 15.