# How to exclude substring from string closing with whitespace?

Tags: python, linux, string, parsing, substring

I would like to exclude substring starting from '>' and closing with ' '.
Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

content = "classTest>528 points"
substring = content['>' : ' ']
print substring     # 528
```

Comment: use `regex` with, `pattern = re.compile(r">(\S+)")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Python Regex Find pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260105/simple-python-regex-find-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use regular expressions (which has a bit of a learning curve), you can use this simpler but longer code.

```
content = "classTest>528 points"
i = content.find('>')
j = content.find(' ', i+1)
substring = content[i+1:j]
print(substring)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up regexes. Here's a minimal working example for your test case:

```
import re

content = "classTest>528 points"
substring = re.search(r'>(\d+) ', content).group(1)
print substring
```

Comment: `">(\S+)"`, would be perfect, he didn't say numbers, did he?

Comment: @SSj.Luffy it might be, but I guessed he's looking for numbers, quite reasonably I think. The point is it's best to learn regexes (they're very useful for lots of things) and decide which works best for OP's use case, of which I've only seen a tiny sample.